# How can I get a list of types from a DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I'd like to point a C# application at a DLL and get a list of the types defined in that DLL.
What I have so far looks right on the surface, but is giving the error indicated below.

```
using System.Reflection;

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly SampleAssembly;
    SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\MyAssembly.dll"); //error happens here

    foreach (Type tp in SampleAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tp.Name);
    }
}

/*
This will give me:
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I wish it would give me something like this:
MyClass1
MyClass2
MyClass3
*/
```

Comment: The same code has just worked correctly for me, using VS2k8.... Does the DLL you're pointing to (1) Definately exist and (2) Is a .net assembly? Also, which line of code are you receiving the error on? I'm suspecting the Assembly.LoadFrom line?

Comment: Why don’t you follow the advice and look at the LoaderExceptions property on the exception for more information?

Comment: @Rob - yes it definitely exists, and it is a .net assembly.  You are correct about the line of code - it happened on the .LoadFrom line.  I've edited my question to make that clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ReflectionOnlyLoad instead of a straight load to prevent the runtime from attempting to run any code in the target assembly

Answer (score 2):

The ReflectionTypeLoadException is being thrown because one of your types is throwing an exception during static initialization.  This can happen if the method/property/field signatures depend on a Type that is not available.  I recommend you catch for that exception and inspect the contents of the exception's LoaderExceptions property as suggested.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I thought the static initialization only takes place when the class is first used.

Comment: @ChaosPandion is right, I tried it. Reflection let me list all the types and all their members without executing the static initializer. Only when I try to instantiate a type, does the initializer kick in and throw.

Comment: That's what I get for working from memory.  I thought that was the case, but nice catch.  Answer edited.