# How to find NuGet packages referenced in code but not in project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# .NET 6 project where I need to find all NuGet packages that are referenced by the C# source but are not directly referenced in the project file. This can happen when the package is a transitive reference.

For example:

- My project contains a reference to package A
- Package A references package B
- My source code references types in package B
- But my project does not contain a reference to package B.

**Project:**

```
<PackageReference Include="A" Version="1.0.0">
<!-- Note, no direct reference to B -->
```

**C# Source:**

```
using B;
// ... class that references types from package B
```

This compiles and runs fine due to the transitive reference from A to B.

I have tried using `dotnet list package`. That only includes direct references.

I have also tried using `dotnet list package --include-transitive`. That includes **all** transitive references, including packages not references by my code.

Internet searches so far are not turning up any third-party utilities that appear to do what I need.

Is there any tool or technique to find the transitive packages referenced by my C# code?

Comment: Why is it important to know which packages your code references directly versus those used by its dependencies? Do you need to find implicit references as well? For example, what if you say `var x = service.Foo()` or `string name = service.Foo().Name` and `service.Foo()` returns a type from another package? (I'm not questioning your need: understanding the root of your question will help produce the kind of answer you're looking for.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I work on a system that uses a large ecosystem of internal NuGet packages. These packages have references to other packages in the ecosystem. It's easy to end up referencing a package from code w/out including a reference to the package in the project. The ecosystem evolves over time. Consequently we need to update all packages to the latest version. The "Manage NuGet Packages" feature in VisualStudio works reasonably well for this, but it only detects updates to packages that are directly referenced.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior This can lead to old versions of internal packages being referenced (transitively), which can cause problems that are not always apparent until runtime.

Comment: Everything you just described applies equally well to all the transitive dependencies, doesn't it? How would an old version of a transitive dependency be less problematic when a package you use simply calls into it, versus one where your code references its types directly?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'm not asking a theoretical question. I'm looking to automate something I've been doing manually. Let's assume I need an answer to the question I asked. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: I have different ideas depending on what your question is really asking. You're saying there are certain types of transitive dependencies you care about and others you don't, but you haven't been clear about how you draw the boundary between them. You've provided the example of the `using` directive targeting a namespace from a transitive dependency, but is that really the limit of the scope of your problem? There are lots of ways to reference types in a library without a `using` directive.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In general, the classes in the packages that have required direct references to be added are referenced through the DI container. Regarding your "implicit" example, I haven't run into any instances of that being an issue, but ideally I'd like to see those packages as well.

Comment: In that case you can [use Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178633/120955) to get a list of all the types that are referenced in your code. You can parse the output of `dotnet list package --transitive` to figure out what nuget packages and versions you're using, find those package folders in nuget's global package folder, use a [reflection-only load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526479/120955) to see what types are declared in each package's DLLs, and compare that with those referenced in your project.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't expect to find a ready-made tool for this use case, because the same kinds of problems that arise from transitive dependencies directly referenced by your code also tend to arise from transitive dependencies only referenced by your other dependencies, so it sounds like the problem you're trying to solve is either unique to your case or not actually the problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to drill down into the dependencies to see the referenced project and it's NuGet Packages.  These are the Transitive packages that can be used by the referencing project.  If I check installed NuGet packages for the project, there are none, but I use Serilog in the project.

[image: Solution Exporer]

Answer (score 0):

Not at a computer to test this right now, but something like

```
grep -F -x -v -f $(dotnet list package) $(dotnet list package --include-transitive)
```

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28159